# % of Grand Total of a Measure that uses other Measures and is Crossfiltered

Tags: powerbi, dax

this seems so easy in my head but I haven't been able to get it for the last few hours....

I have a Table visualization that provides Cost by Hour using measures.

```
Category | Total Cost | Hours  | Cost per Hour
A        | 1000       | 10     |  100
B        | 2000       | 100    |   20
C        | 100        | 4      |   25  
D        | -500       | 100    |  -5
Total    | 2600       | 214    | 12.1495
```

For my purposes, I would also like to create a % of Grand Total of Cost per hour to add to a treechart visualization. However, if I simply add [Cost per Hour] to the treechart again and use the "quick clac" functionality on the field it would return 823.7% for the first record in the above table as (100/12.1495) = 8.2307. I would like this % of GT of Cost per Hour to use the total sum of the Cost per Hour column. Desired Result:

```
Category | Total Cost | Hours  | Cost per Hour | % of Cost per Hour
A        | 1000       | 10     |  100          | 71.4%
B        | 2000       | 100    |   20          | 14.3%
C        | 100        | 4      |   25          | 17.9%
D        | -500       | 100    |  -5           | -3.8%
Total    | 2600       | 214    | 12.1495       | 100%
```

A few things to note that makes the application of any DAX challenging. All of the below Measures are filtered by multiple filter visualizations from Tables 1-5 and page level filters from Tables 1-5

The table visualization exists in Table1. Costs exist in Tables 2-5 and are related to Table1 using a Many-to-One Single Direction Filter Relationship.

[Total Cost] is a Measure that adds together values from 4 different tables. Eg:`Total Cost = sum(table2[value])+sum(table3[value])+sum(table4[value])+sum(table5[value])`

[Hours] is a Measure that adds together a column from a table and divides by the distinct count of records in that table. Eg:`Hours = sum(table1[hours])/Distinctcount(table1[records])`

[Cost per Hour] is a Measure consisting of two other measure.`Cost per Hour = [Total Cost] / [Hours]`

I sort of feel like this is similar to people wanting to add percentages to pie charts... I'm just trying to ascribe a real number to express the proportion displayed in the TreeChart visualization. I really hope that this is easier than it seems.

EDIT @alejandrozuleta: 
Table1 is the original table from which tables 2-5 are referenced&created. An index number was assigned in Table1 and tables 2-5 are linked on this reference number. The reason that tables 2-5 exists separately is because they contain separate cost "types" and a join that occurs in these tables adds additional columns that are only applicable to specific costs types.... for example Table2 is Personnel Costs:

```
index | Category | Cost Type |  Value | Age of Personnel
1     | A        | Personnel | 1      | 33
```

and Table3 is Maintenance Costs:

```
index | Category | Cost Type   |  Value | Scheduled or UnScheduled Maint
2     | A        | Maintenance | 5      | Scheduled
```

The if `[Age of Personnel]` existed in Table3 then it would have a "null" for any record of the Maintenance `[Cost Type]` vice-versa `[Scheduled or UnScheduled Maint]` would have a "null" if it existed in Table2. Because I don't want to have to deal with filter visualizations needing to select "(blanks)" for certain costs types the data relationship between these tables is a Many-to-One Single Direction Filter using `[index]` as the key.

EDIT2:
Working .pbix file with notional data and the data model I described is linked:
[StackOverflow_GTofMeasure_Crosfilltered.pbix](http://markgaal.com/powerbiquestions/StackOverflow_GTofMeasure_Crosfilltered.pbix)

Comment: Could you add tables 2,3,4,5 sample data and exaplain better how these are related to table 1.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta added information per your request.

Answer (score 3):

I think this solution could work for you. Basically I've created two helper measures (which you don't have to show in your table):

`CostPerHourHelper = SUMX(TableName,[Cost per Hour])`

`CostPerHourTotal = SUMX(ALL(TableName),[Cost per Hour])`

Now you can create your `% of Cost per Hour` measure using this expression:

```
% Cost Per Hour = [CostPerHourHelper]/[CostPerHourTotal]
```

It should produce:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Use `ALLSELECTED()` function to preserve the explicit filters you applied.

```
% Cost Per Hour = SUMX ( TableName, [Cost per Hour] )
    / SUMX ( ALLSELECTED ( TableName ), [Cost per Hour] )
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: question is [Cost per Hour] a measure or a calculated column in Table1?

Comment: @MarkDavidGaal, It is your `[Cost per Hour]` measure.

Comment: Hmmm, this may work... if you recall in my original post I mentioned that I use several filter visualizations from both Table1 and Tables 2-5. Wouldn't I have to add those into your [CostPerHourTotal] measure instead of simply using the ALL() function? If so, what is the best method of getting ALL returned with except specific filtering columns from multiple tables?

Comment: @MarkDavidGaal, Try using `ALLSELECTED()` instead of `ALL()` function. It is hard to test without sample data and filters you are using.

Comment: Hmmm, ah that's so much easier than naming each ALLEXCEPT! Getting closer; however, it appears that the [CostPerHourHelper] and [CostPerHourTotal] aren't producing the right numbers... my thoughts are this is because category A, B, C, D, etc... appear multiple times in the source data for Table1 and that it then sums the per hour value by record? Do you have a sample .pbix file you've been working from? Can you upload then I can modify it to have some some sample data and we can go from there....?

Comment: @MarkDavidGaal, Note if you have repeated categories in table1 it affects the `SUM(Table1[Hours]) and `Distinctcount(table1[records])` are you ok with that? or do you need only one hours value for every category?. Try add every table and 5 or more rows to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I've updated the OP with a .pbix file with data from table 1, 2, and 3 and the many-to-one single direction filter data model that I described earlier.
http://markgaal.com/powerbiquestions/StackOverflow_GTofMeasure_Crosfilltered.pbix

Comment: was the .pbix file i created helpful? Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: @MarkDavidGaal, I just created the measure suggested in the last update to my answer and it shows your desired table, also if I filter category using the slicer in your power bi file I get the values you defined as correct. I don't understand what your issue is. Note Personel and Maintance slicers don't filter your data since your tables have no relationship with `table1`.